# How to Set Background image of div with ng-style

Tags: angularjs

Basically i have a link, and when it's clicked, i display a modal. Now i can display other properties on the modal like title except the background Image ! urghhh !

This is the modal:

```
<div class="modalContainer" ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{selectedMeal.url}})'}">

                <div id="modalHeader"> 
                <div style="padding-top: 10px;">{{selectedMeal.title}}</div>

                </div>
</div>
```

These are the links:

```
<div ng-click='selectMeal(meal)' class="contentItem" ng-repeat='meal in recipes | filter:searchText' ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{ meal.url }})'}">
                    <span id="contentItemHeader">{{ meal.title }}</span>
                    <span id="contentItemLevel">{{ meal.level }}</span>
</div>
```

json:

```
recipes:[
    {
      "type": "Breakfast",
      "title": "Chili con carne",
      "description": "A spicy and fragrant chili with ground beef, kidney beans, tomatoes, onions and garlic. Best served over rice with a dollop of sour cream and some cheese on top.",
      "ratings": 4,
      "duration": 12,
      "level":"medium",
      "url":"http://31.media.tumblr.com/bc0ea7c5f95701bff499f78b59d23e68/tumblr_mr74z9Lt3O1rs0z5go1_500.jpg",
      "ingredients": 
          [
            {
              "vegetable": "40ml"
            }
          ],
      "method": 
          [
            {
              "1": "In a medium sized stock pot, heat the oil over  heat. Saute onions, chile peppers andgarlic until soft."
            }
          ]
    },

    {
      "type": "Breakfast",
      "title": "Spicy Noodle",
      "description": "A spicy and fragrant chili with ground beef, kidney beans, tomatoes, onions and garlic. Best served over rice with a dollop of sour cream and some cheese on top.",
      "ratings": 5,
      "duration": 30,
      "level":"hot",
      "url":"http://38.media.tumblr.com/875b5eeb5b1efa37d2e9d36fbad836d3/tumblr_mzczesVrZD1rimr6yo1_1280.jpg",
      "ingredients": 
          [
            {
              "vegetable": "40ml"
            }
          ],
      "method": 
          [
            {
              "1": "In a  sized stock pot, heat the oil over  heat. Saute onions, chile peppers andgarlic until soft."
            }
          ]
    }]
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You have made some mistakes using single quotes, you have to take your variable outside the single quotes.

For this div

```
<div class="modalContainer" ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{selectedMeal.url}})'}">
```

This part is being treated as a string

```
'url({{selectedMeal.url}})'
```

Whereas you would want angular to parse this variable

```
{{selectedMeal.url}}
```

So to solve this, the correct syntax is

```
<div class="modalContainer" 
  ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + selectedMeal.url + ')'}">
```

Comment: You saved me, this syntax: 'url(' + selectedMeal.url + ')' is the one that works, the others with {{}} DON'T ...

Answer (score 11):

Correct syntax for background-image is:

```
background-image: url("src");
```

Correct syntax for ng-style is:

```
 <div ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{re.url}})'}" ></div>
```

**for example :**

```
<div ng-repeat="re in recipes">
<div ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{re.url}})'}" style="height: 100px"></div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/7194/

**also**  You can use **custom directive :**

```
app.directive('backgroundImageDirective', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.css({
            'background-image': 'url(' + attrs.backgroundImageDirective + ')',
            'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
        });
    };
});
```

**for example :**

```
<div ng-repeat="re in recipes">
<div background-image-directive="{{re.url}}" style="height: 100px"></div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/7193/

**Update :**

```
<div ng-style="'{{re.url}}' != '' && {'background-image':'url({{re.url}})'}" style="height: 100px"></div>
```

which would not attempt to fetch a non-existing image.

Answer (score 9):

This is work for me. If you are retrieve data from json or any other try this

```
<div class="your-class" [style.background-image]="'url(' + url.image + ')'" [ngStyle]="{  'background-size': 'cover','background-repeat': 'no-repeat'} ">
```