# Dynamically seting a background image using AngularJs Controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi I have the following code to set the background to the whole page, and it works fine the background image is showed as expected, but the chrome console show this errors

```
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/img/backgrounds/%7B%7Bbgimg%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/img/backgrounds/ 404 (Not Found)
```

This error is similar when loading image with `src` instead of `ng-src` but for background I don't know any directive. here is my code

HTML:

```
<body background="assets/img/backgrounds/{{bgimg}}">
<div class="view-container layer">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

The controller

```
    var bgImagesList = ['01.jpg',
        '02.jpg', '03.jpg', '04.jpg',
        '05.jpg', '06.jpg', '07.jpg',
        '08.jpg', '09.jpg', '10.jpg',
        '11.jpg'];

    var changeBaclground = function () {
        $rootScope.bgimg = bgImagesList[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgImagesList.length)];
    };
```

Comment: You could consider using `ng-class` or `ng-style` I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ng-style for this purpose

```
<body ng-style="{'background-image':'url(assets/img/backgrounds/{{bgimg}})'}" >
```

Other easy way will be
  html:

```
<body ng-style="setBackground()" >
```

In Controller:

```
var bgimg = bgImagesList[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgImagesList.length)];   

$rootScope.setBackground = function(){
    return {
            'background-image':'url(assets/img/backgrounds/' + bgimg + ')'
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried this `<body ng-style="{'background-image':'assets/img/backgrounds/{{bgimg}})'}">` and this `<body ng-style="{'background-image':'assets/img/backgrounds/bgimg)'}">` but didn't work . I am using it correctly?

Comment: please see my code, you need to enclose path in url()

Comment: Ups sorry, but didn't work, now the resultan code is `<body ng-style="{'background-image':'url(assets/img/backgrounds/07.jpg)'}" style="background-image: url(http://localhost:3000/assets/img/backgrounds/);">` and the background is missing

Comment: @efirvida i have edited my answer and added another way. Try that.

Comment: that last works perfectly, thanks!, I edited to have the full code

Answer (score 2):

I'd possibly consider using `ng-style` for a solution.

Inside your controller when you change the background, update a style object in your `$scope` which is reference by `ng-style` of the element.

See some info about `ng-style` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle).

**UPDATE**

See the following plunkr [http://plnkr.co/edit/dYIQ...](http://plnkr.co/edit/dYIQ0NzhGiJVeSH4EZDe?p=preview) that shows a simple use of `ng-style`. When you check and uncheck the checkbox the background color will change between red and blue.

For your problem, your `myStyle` object could be something like;

```
var myStyle = {
  background: 'url(path/to/' + bgimg + ')'
}
```

Ideally, you won't need to create the `myStyle` variable each time but the example gives you a simple example of how it can be used.

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: I saw the documentation but didn't figure out on who to do it

Comment: I've updated my answer with a plunkr to show you what I mean. Simply check the checkbox and see the background color change between red and blue.

Comment: In later updates I believe you could just do changes like `myStyle.background = 'url(...)';` instead of creating the object again. This is just a simple way to show you how it works.

Comment: What does your `$rootScope.myStyle` object look like? have you followed how I used it in the plunker?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-style` with your element, this is how to set it:

```
ng-style="{'background-image':'url(assets/img/backgrounds/{{bgimg}})'}"
```

And this is how your whole code should be:

```
<body ng-style="{'background-image':'url(assets/img/backgrounds/{{bgimg}})'}">
<div class="view-container layer">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

You can read more about it at **[ngStyle
- directive in module ng](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)** and you will find how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24902075/3669624).

Comment: as I said in other comment with this I have a resultant HTML like `<body ng-style="{'background-image':'url(assets/img/backgrounds/07.jpg)'}" style="background-image: url(http://localhost:3000/assets/img/backgrounds/);"> ` and now the background is missing because `style="background-image: url(http://localhost:3000/assets/img/backgrounds/);"` don't have the image url

Comment: Where are your html file and image located, are they in the same folde? please show us the directory tree. I think you may use `../assets/img/backgrounds/{{bgimg}}` if the assets folder and your current html file are in the same directory.