# Changing background image of div with ng-style

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I know this has been asked and answered in the past ([How to Set Background image of div with ng-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899699/how-to-set-background-image-of-div-with-ng-style)) but something is not working for me, and I don't know what.  I want to create an image that can be changed one quarter at a time by clicking in that quarter.  So, click in the upper left, change the upper left part of the image, and so forth. (In the example below, the initial picture is a frog in the palm of a hand, and the frog would disappear a quarter at a time.)  I have succeeded in displaying the initial image, but clicking is not accomplishing anything.

Tried to create a jsfiddle but the Angular module won't load there for some reason (http://jsfiddle.net/mhurwicz/4znn36gg/7/).

Here is a live version that does display the initial image but doesn't change as I'd like it to when clicked:

http://greendept.com/rana/ranatest.html

Here is my code from the above URL:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ranatest</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        ()
        angular.module('myRanaAurora', []).controller('MyRanaAuroraController', function($scope, $timeout) {
            $scope.topLurl = "palm_with_frog.gif";
            $scope.topRurl = "palm_with_frog.gif";
            $scope.botLurl = "palm_with_frog.gif";
            $scope.botRurl = "palm_with_frog.gif";
            $scope.buttonPress = function (btn) {
                if (btn == 'topLurl') {
                    $scope.topLurl = "palm.gif";
                }
                else if (btn == 'topRurl') {$scope.topRurl = "palm.gif";}
                else if (btn == 'botLurl') {$scope.botLurl = "palm.gif";}
                else if (btn == 'botRurl') {$scope.botRurl = "palm.gif";}
            };
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #container {
            position: absolute;
            height: 250px;
        }

        #topL {
            width: 125px;
            height: 125px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #topR {
            width: 125px;
            height: 125px;
            margin-left: 125px;
            margin-top: -125px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #botL {
            width: 125px;
            height: 125px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #botR {
            width: 125px;
            height: 125px;
            margin-left: 125px;
            margin-top: -125px;
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="myRanaAurora" ng-controller="MyRanaAuroraController">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="topL" ng-mousedown="buttonPress('topLurl')" ng-style="{'background': 'url({{topLurl}}) left top'}"></div>
        <div id="topR" ng-mousedown="buttonPress('topRurl')" ng-style="{'background': 'url({{topRurl}}) right top'}"></div>
        <div id="botL" ng-mousedown="buttonPress('botLurl')" ng-style="{'background': 'url({{botLurl}}) left bottom'}"></div>
        <div id="botR" ng-mousedown="buttonPress('botRurl')" ng-style="{'background': 'url({{botRurl}}) right bottom'}"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why don't you try adding a class on click? create those classes in css with background and onclick added/remove classes. Thats simple to do

Comment: try `ng-click` instead `ng-mousedown`

Comment: @VishwaKumar - True, although if I go that route, I'll probably use jQuery.  But if only to educate myself, I'd like to find out what I'm doing wrong here, too.

Comment: @fodma1 - The clicking part is working: `buttonPress` is executing.  What would `ng-click` do that `ng-mousedown` isn't doing?

Comment: @user1147171: hey, I added your code in a plunkr, and tried fixing the same.  http://plnkr.co/edit/CrQfB2UwoRYtolUj1jZF?p=preview

Comment: @shivi  That does the trick! Thank you!

Comment: For those who come after, the keys to success seem to be:  1) put the background position in CSS instead of `ng-style`, and use `background-image` instead of `background` in `ng-style`, and  2)  use `url(' + topLurl + ')'` instead of `url({{topLurl}})'` in `ng-style`

Comment: One thing I still don't understand is why `url({{topLurl}})'` works to display the initial picture but not the "substitute" picture.  If anyone knows how this works, I'd be interested.