# angularjs background image not working on span tag

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to apply a background image to a span tag by using the angular ng-style , when span tag is clicked it calls chgImg but it doesn't seem to be working. Its working if I am directly replacing {{img}} with /images/chk.svg

```
 <span ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{img}})'}" ng-click="chgImg()" class="Pollchoice--radio">{{img}}
 </span>
```

AngularCode:

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts',
function($scope, posts) {
    $scope.posts = posts.posts;

    $scope.chgImg = function(){
        $scope.img = "/images/chk.svg"; 
    };
}
```

]);

Comment: use this reference:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899699/how-to-set-background-image-of-div-with-ng-style

Comment: @Himanshu thanks for reference its working :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use *$scope.apply* as below:

```
$scope.chgImg = function(){
  $scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.img = "/images/chk.svg"; 
  });
};
```