# How to change body background image by clicking a button in Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Hello I am adding buttons to my website that allow users to change the background.

I am trying to make the background change with Angular.

So far I have successfully been able to change the background color a couple ways (changing to a single color and gradient)... however, I am trying to change the background-image with one button and the other button I am trying to change the background gradient and background-size at the same time.

These are the steps I have done so far:

1. `<body ng-style="myStyle">`

   - **Successful:** `<input type="button" class="bg stripes" ng-click="myStyle={background: 'red'}">`
   - **Failing:** `<input type="button" class="bg numbers" ng-click="myStyle={background-image:'url(../images/count2.png)'}">`
   - **Successful:** `<input type="button" class="bg stripes" ng-click="myStyle={background:'linear-gradient(45deg, #379690 25%, #3aa19b 25%, #3aa19b 50%, #379690 50%, #379690 75%, #3aa19b 75%, #3aa19b)'}">`
   - **Failing:** `<input type="button" class="bg stripes" ng-click="myStyle={background:'linear-gradient(45deg, #379690 25%, #3aa19b 25%, #3aa19b 50%, #379690 50%, #379690 75%, #3aa19b 75%, #3aa19b)',background-size:'100px 100px'}">`

Please help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use **[ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)**

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24902075/1398867)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Set Background image of div with ng-style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899699/how-to-set-background-image-of-div-with-ng-style)

Comment: Thanks for commenting so quickly... However I've tried those things... it must have something to do with where my quotes are located. I am trying to change backgrounds of the body with ng-click --- I do not want to set the style of that input....

Comment: Why vote this down? I am trying to set background of a different area other than the tags I am in.... this is not a duplicate question

Comment: @Venugopal please explain how those are the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with the syntax. You need to wrap `background-image` key in quotes, otherwise it's not a valid identifier. It works with `background` because having nothing but alpha characters, it doesn't require quotes.

```
<input type="button" class="bg numbers" ng-click="myStyle={'background-image': 'url(../images/count2.png)'}">
```

Then it will work properly:

```js
angular.module('demo', [])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-app="demo" ng-style="myStyle">

  <input type="button" class="bg numbers" ng-click="myStyle={'background-image': 'url(http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/dark_embroidery.png)'}" value="Set background">

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the issue.... funny it worked without quotes for solid colors and the gradient...

Comment: Wouldn't this override existing styles if the other button is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to redefine the `myStyle` object each time.

In your ng-click you could

```
ng-click="myStyle.background='...';myStyle.backgroundSize='...'"
```

You can fiddle around this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cattails27/gzd1ttra/1/).

Comment: Thank you!! This fixed the problem too!