# Dynamic background image with Angular JS ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, background-image

Id like to display dynamic background images using angular's `ng-repeat` directive.

At the moment Im doing this by setting it as an inline style like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things" 
     style="background-image: url({{thing.image}})" >
</div
```

I would prefer to use standard angular tools to accomplish this and avoid using inline styles. I would set a static background image using `ng-style` but this does not seem practical for an indeterminate number of objects.

What is the correct solution for something like this?

Comment: use ng-class based on the repeat.

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899699/how-to-set-background-image-of-div-with-ng-style it has a multitude of ways to do it. I'm sure one of these ways is what you are looking for.

Comment: i think with your ng-style is good some thing like this `<div ng-repeat="thing in things" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(thing.image)'}" >
</div`

Answer (score 2):

you can use it into `<img>` tags like below

```
<img ng-repeat="x in array" src="{{ x.image_url }}" style="static inline stylesheet" />
```

or use

```
<img ng-repeat="x in array" ng-src="x.image_url" style="static inline stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 2):

To set an image dynamically, suggest to use ng-src

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things">
     <img ng-src="{{thing.ImageUrl}}" />
</div
```

This would then give you expected result, because thing.ImageUrl is evaluated and replaced by its value after angular is loaded.

Update as a background Image now

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + thing.ImageUrl + ')'}"></div
```

Comment: but that make an img element. no background image in the div.

Comment: thats an example let me put a background image style in the div in an edit