# How to add a background image to a div in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to add a background image to a div but having some issues doing this. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45632663/how-to-set-angular-4-background-image) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899699/how-to-set-background-image-of-div-with-ng-style)  solutions on SO for adding a background image to a div but after trying those solutions I still get the following error

> TS2339: Property 'addi' does not exist on type 'CheckoutComponent'.

> 13 <div class="myrow" [style.background]="'url(./images/' + addi.jpg+ ')'" >

I placed the image folder under both src/images/addi.jpg and src/app/checkout/images/addi.jpg but still getting the same error. Here is my div block for which I am trying to add the background image

```html
<div class="myrow" [style.background]="'url(./images/' + addi.jpg + ')'">
    <div class="col-3">
        <div class="container">
            <form #addressForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(addressForm.value)" (keyup)="setDirtyStatus()">
                <div class="myrow">
                    <div class="col-50">
                        <h3>Billing Address</h3>
                        <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="fullnames.invalid && fullnames.touched" [class.has-success]="fullnames.valid">
                            <label class="control-label" for="fname"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Full Name</label>
                            <input required #fullnames="ngModel" class="form-control" type="text" id="fname" name="fname" ngModel />
                            <span *ngIf="fullnames.invalid && fullnames.touched" class="help-block">Name is required</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="myemail.invalid && myemail.touched" [class.has-success]="myemail.valid">
                            <label class="control-label" for="email"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Email</label>
                            <input required #myemail="ngModel" class="form-control" email type="text" id="email" name="email" ngModel />
                            <span *ngIf="myemail.invalid && myemail.touched" class="help-block">Email is not valid</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="delieveryAddress.invalid && delieveryAddress.touched" [class.has-success]="delieveryAddress.valid">
                            <label class="control-label" for="adr"><i class="fa fa-address-card-o"></i> Address</label>
                            <input required #delieveryAddress="ngModel" class="form-control" type="text" id="adr" name="address" ngModel />
                            <span *ngIf="delieveryAddress.invalid && delieveryAddress.touched" class="help-block">Address is required</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="city.invalid && city.touched" [class.has-success]="city.valid">
                            <label class="control-label" for="city"><i class="fa fa-institution"></i> City</label>
                            <input required #city="ngModel" class="form-control" type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="New York" ngModel />
                            <span *ngIf="city.invalid && city.touched" class="help-block">City is required</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="myrow">
                            <div class="col-50">
                                <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="state.invalid && state.touched" [class.has-success]="state.valid">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="state">State</label>
                                    <input required #state="ngModel" class="form-control" type="text" id="state" name="state" placeholder="NY" ngModel />
                                    <span *ngIf="state.invalid && state.touched" class="help-block">State is required</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-50">
                                <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="zip.invalid && zip.touched" [class.has-success]="zip.valid">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="zip">Zip</label>
                                    <input required #zip="ngModel" class="form-control" type="text" id="zip" name="zip" placeholder="10001" ngModel />
                                    <span *ngIf="zip.invalid && zip.touched" class="help-block">Postal code is required</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <label> <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="sameadr" /> Shipping address same as billing </label>
                <button type="submit" class="btn" [disabled]="addressForm.invalid">Next step</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am still new with angular and it would be nice to know where exactly to place this folder

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<div class="myrow" [style.background]={'url("./images/addi.jpg")'} >
```

Or simply just add a class for that image syle and add the class next to my row. and use the class. As I can tell you do not want to dynamically change the background like in your examples you just want to set a background image. so just use CSS for that.

Comment: I tried that now and got a new error. it says **This expression is not callable.Type 'String' has no call signatures.** Where exactly can i place the image folder?

Comment: I don't think that your problem has to do with the images folder location. Just add the image via CSS.